# read multiple struct from binary file in c#

Tags: c#, struct

i want to insert data in a binary file.Data is 50 struct.i want to save features of soft music files in binary file as database that i can use it.

i built a struct to each song,and insert it in file.
struct contain:

```
public struct  s {
    public byte class_no;
    public int sample_no;
    public byte [] template;
}
```

where template is a 1-d array of size 4410 
my file now contain 50 struct and i want to read it using binary file and make array of struct of all structs in file

Comment: what kind of database? or what database product are you using?

Comment: i want to use text file to save features of soft music in text file,ok ,i save the features but i want to read them from file.in other meaning.. i want to read a struct from file and save it in 2-d array,each row contain a single struct that read from file.my question is how can i read multiple struct from file ??

Comment: what code did you use to get this struct into a file?

Answer (score 0):

I will answer reading multiple structs from file.

this example defines a structure for holding data which you will need to do your own thing with.

none of this is designed for your specific needs but as a general how to save and read back a list of structure you define your self

full code you can copy and paste into a fresh console app project:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

using System.IO;

//where the magic lives
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;

namespace savecon
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Random rand = new Random();

        byte[] data = new byte[20];

        rand.NextBytes(data);

        DataObj a = new DataObj(data);
        DataObj b = new DataObj(data);

        DataCollection dc_old = new DataCollection();
        dc_old.Add(a);
        dc_old.Add(b);

        DataCollection.ToFile("D:\\data.my",dc_old);//I use D: drive yours will be different

        DataCollection dc_new = DataCollection.FromFile("D:\\data.my");



    }
}

[Serializable]//the magic
struct DataObj
{ 
    byte[] data;
    public DataObj(byte[] d)
    {
        data = d;
    }
}


[Serializable]//more magic
class DataCollection : IEnumerable<DataObj>
{
    List<DataObj> dataobjects;//list<> is Attributed with Serializable as well
    public DataCollection()
    {
        dataobjects = new List<DataObj>();
    }


    public static DataCollection FromFile(string path)
    {
        DataCollection dcol;

        using (FileStream FS = File.OpenRead(path))
        {
            dcol = (DataCollection)new BinaryFormatter().Deserialize(FS); // magic happening
        }

        return dcol;
    }


    public static void ToFile(string path,DataCollection DC)
    {
        using (FileStream FS = File.Open(path, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
        {
            new BinaryFormatter().Serialize(FS, DC);
        }
    }


    public void Add(DataObj dobj)
    {
        dataobjects.Add(dobj);
    }




    //note that Ienumerable does not matter for serializing (saving the data)

    public IEnumerator<DataObj> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return dataobjects.AsEnumerable().GetEnumerator();
    }

    System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return dataobjects.GetEnumerator();
    }
}
}
```